# Meaning of "controversy surrounding"

Tags: meaning

> The controversy surrounding [something]

If there are 2 sides, 1 side supporting [something] and another side opposing [something], which side does it represent?

Comment: Neither. It means the controversy concerning something.

Comment: What does "surrounding" mean?

Comment: And what does "controversy" mean?  If it was all supporting or all opposing then there would be no controversy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both. Controversy involves disagreement.

Thus, there are some people supportive of/pushing for [something] and some against/rejecting [something].

Following the common metaphor, surrounding implies that there are two (or more) 'sides' of a debate.